# What are good cross-platform Game API?

Tags: cross-platform

I am in the process of designing/building a cross-platform game engine in C++.  I would like to use an game API that has 2D/3D graphics, input, networking, audio, etc.  One API I found that meets many of these requirements except for Audio is [Amaltheia](http://home.gna.org/amaltheia/).  Can anyone suggest an API that meets all my requirements or one that meets most of the requirements that is better than [Amaltheia](http://home.gna.org/amaltheia/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could look at [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), it's a popular cross-platform multimedia library used in many games.

Also the [Game Programming Wiki](http://web.archive.org/web/20090301052144/http://gpwiki.org/) is a good source for lists of game programming [libraries](http://web.archive.org/web/20090301053452/http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Libraries) and [engines](http://web.archive.org/web/20090301042508/http://gpwiki.org/index.php/Game_Engines)

Answer (score 11):

Lots of people are using [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) these days<del>, which is a bit more up to date than SDL.</del>

(Answer edited as SDL finally saw an update since I originally posted this! SFML is still a worthy choice, however.)

Comment: Not only up to date, better organisation too!

Comment: hard to implement for mac though, 1.6 doesn't have any guide for xcode 4

Comment: This is no longer true since the release of SDL2.

Answer (score 3):

[Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/) is very popular.  There is also a big community site for it [here](http://www.allegro.cc/).

Comment: Note: Allegro now has two branches, for all tastes, one supports legacy hardware, software rendering (for both 3D and 2D), and has OpenGL support that still supports you 2D code (unlike SDL, that if you use OpenGL you have to code using OpenGL directly, you can in Allegro 4.4 just load the OpenGL driver, and code like if you was using DirectDraw... it is REALLY cool, OpenGL Blit() ) the other branch, that will be in future 5.0, supports native OpenGL and D3D (if on windows, of course), but no software rendering... But it has better API

Answer (score 1):

In case you get tired of C++, there's also something simpler: BlitzBasic

http://www.blitzbasic.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Unity Engine](http://unity3d.com/) if your authoring is done in OSX

Comment: Unity's Editor works in Windows, and compiles windows executables.

Comment: @Robert, Unity is crossplatform and it compiles applications for (various platforms)[http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform]

Comment: Yeah I meant to say it "also" works in Windows, I'm not implying it only works in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[Ideaworks 3D](http://www4.ideaworks3d.com/) has a great API that works on more systems than you could shake a stick at (including windows and linux), does networking, sound and 3d.  It's a bit expensive though...