# How portable IS C++?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

In C++, if I write a simple game like pong using Linux, can that same code be compiled on Windows and OSX? Where can I tell it won't be able to be compiled?

Comment: that depends on what libraries/functions you use exactly and whether they are available for all platforms...

Answer (score 17):

You have three major portability hurdles.

The first, and simplest, is writing C++ code that all the target compilers understand.  Note: this is different from writing to the C++ standard.  The problem with "writing to the standard" starts with: which standard?  You have [C++98, C++03, C++TR1 or C++11 or C++14 or C++17](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/C++#C.2FC.2B.2B_standards)?  These are all revisions to C++ and the newer one you use the less compliant compilers are likely to be.  C++ is very large, and realistically the best you can hope for is C++98 with some C++03 features.

Compilers all add their own extensions, and it's all too easy to unknowingly use them.  You would be wise to write to the standard and not to the compiler documentation.  Some compilers have a "strict" mode where they will turn off all extensions.  You would be wise to do primary development in the compiler which has the most strictures and the best standard compliance.  `gcc` has the `-Wstrict` family of flags to turn on strict warnings.  `-ansi` will remove extensions which conflict with the standard.  `-std=c++98` will tell the compiler to work against the C++98 standard and remove GNU C++ extensions.

With that in mind, to remain sane you must restrict yourself to a handful of compilers and only their recent versions.  Even writing a relatively simple C library for multiple compilers is difficult.  Fortunately, both Linux and OS X use gcc.  Windows has Visual C++, but different versions are more like a squabbling family than a single compiler when it comes to compatibility (with the standard or each other), so you'll have to pick a version or two to support.  Alternatively, you can use one of the gcc derived compiler environments such as [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). Check the [list of C++ compilers]([less compliant compilers are likely to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers?oldformat=true#C++_compilers)) for compatibility information, but keep in mind this is only for the latest version.

Next is your graphics and sound library.  It has to not just be cross platform, it has to look good and be fast on all platforms.  These days there's a lot of possibilities, [Simple DirectMedia Layer](http://www.libsdl.org/) is one.  You'll have to choose at what level you want to code.  Do you want detailed control?  Or do you want an engine to take care of things?  [There's an existing answer for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470520/what-are-good-cross-platform-game-api) so I won't go into details.  Be sure to choose one that is dedicated to being cross platform, not just happens to work.  Compatibility bugs in your graphics library can sink your project fast.

Finally, there's the simple incompatibilities which exist between the operating systems.  POSIX compliance has come a long way, and you're lucky that both Linux and OS X are Unix under the hood, but Windows will always be the odd man out.  Things which are likely to bite you mostly have to do with the filesystem.  Here's a handful:

- Filesystem layout
- File path syntax (ie. C:\foo\bar vs /foo/bar)
- [Mandatory Windows file locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546504/how-do-i-make-windows-file-locking-more-like-unix-file-locking)
- Differing file permissions systems
- Differing models of interprocess communication (ie. fork, shared memory, etc...)
- Differing threading models (your graphics library should smooth this out)

There you have it.  What a mess, huh?  Cross-platform programming is as much a state of mind and statement of purpose as it is a technique.  It requires some dedication and extra time.  There are some things you can do to make the process less grueling...

- Turn on all strictures and warnings *and fix them*
- Turn off all language extensions
- Periodically compile and test in Windows, not just at the end
- Get programmer who likes Windows on the project
- Restrict yourself to as few compilers as you can
- Choose a well maintained, well supported graphics library
- Isolate platform specific code (for example, in a subclass)
- Treat Windows as a first class citizen

The most important thing is to *do this all from the start*.  Portability is not something you bolt on at the end.  Not just your code, but your whole design can become unportable if you're not vigilant.

Comment: `The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from.` ;-)

Comment: "Fortunately, both Linux and OS X use gcc" -- now, eleven years later, macOS has used Clang instead of gcc for quite some time.

Answer (score 8):

C++ is ultra portable and has compilers available on more platforms than you can shake a stick at. Languages like Java are typically touted as being massively cross platform, ironically they are in fact usually implemented in C++, or C.

That covers "portability". If you actually mean, how cross platform is C++, then not so much: The C++ standard only defines an IO library suitable for console IO - i.e. text based, so as soon as you want develop some kind of GUI, you are going to need to use a GUI framework - and GUI frameworks are historically very platform specific. Windows has multiple "native" GUI frameworks now - the C++ framework made available from Microsoft is still MFC - which wraps the native Win32 API which is a C API. (WPF and WinForms are available to CLR C++).

The Apple Mac's GUI framework is called Cocoa, and is an objective-C library, but its easy to access Objective C from C++ in that development environment.

On Linux there is the GTK+ and Qt frameworks that are both actually ported to Windows and Apple, so one of these C++ frameworks can solve your "how to write a GUI application in C++ once that builds and runs on windows, apple mac and linux".

Of course, its difficult to regard Qt as strictly C++ anymore - Qt defines a special markup for signals and slots that requires a pre-compile compile step.

Comment: Even text I/O is difficult to do portably if you need non-ASCII characters.

Comment: The dig at Java because it's implemented in C++ is a red herring.  Perl, Python and Ruby are written in C, but they're far more portable and C remains a nightmare to code cross platform.

Comment: There's also a compiler for sticks, although shaking is not atomic and you need to watch memory use.

Answer (score 4):

You can read the standard - if a program respects the standard, it should be compilable on all platforms that have a C++ standard-compliant compiler.

As for 3rd party libraries you might be using, the platform availability is usually specified in the documentation.

When GUI comes to question, there are cross-platform options (such as QT), but you should probably ask yourself - do I really want portability when it comes to UI? Sometimes, it's better to have the GUI part platform-specific.

Comment: Of course, there are no standard-compliant compilers [there used to be one, but then the standard changed], plus the multitude of implementation defined behavior, so "respecting the standard" is only step one.

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking of porting from Linux to Windows, using `OPENGL` for the graphical part gives you freedom to run your program on both operating systems as long as you don't use any system specific functionality.

Answer (score -4):

Compared to C, C++ portability is extremely limited, if not completely unexisting. For one you can't disable exceptions (well you can), for the standard specifically says that's undefined behaviour. Many devices don't even support exceptions. So as for that, C++ is ZERO portable. Plus seeing the UB, it's obvioulsy a no-go for zero-fail high-performance real time systems in which exceptions are taboo - undefined behaviour has no place in zero-fail environment. Then there's the name mangling which most, if not every, compiler does completely different. For good portability and inter-compatibility extern "C" would have to be used to export symbols, yet this renders any and all namespace information completely void, resulting in duplicate symbols. One can ofcourse choose to not use namespaces and use unique symbol names. Yet another C++ feature rendered void. Then there's the complexity of the language, which results in implementation difficulties in the various compilers for various architectures. Due to these difficulties, true portability becomes a problem. One can solve this by having a large chain of compiler directives/#ifdefs/macros. Templates? Not even supported by most compilers.

What portability? You mean the semi-portability between a couple of main-stream build targets like MSVC for Windows and GCC for Linux? Even there, in that MAIN-STREAM segment, all the above problems and limitations exist. It's retarded to even think C++ is portable.

Comment: Most of the points you put forth are unrelated to the question asked: *"Can I compile compliant C++ code across different platform?"* and the answer to that question suffers from **none** of the issues you described. You cannot (and will not) disable exceptions, because then it wouldn't be C++ anymore. Name mangling is not an issue either. It's a contract between the compiler and the linker, and they will agree for any given tool chain. Lacking template support? Uhm... yeah. That was last millennium.